# How can return a matrix pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, matrix, return

I have a big problem, i want to put a matrix pointer of objects to a function but i don't know how can do this, the objects that i use they are from derived class. This is an example of my code. Note: class Piece is a base class and class Queen is a derived class from Piece

```
#include "Queen.h" 

void changeToQueen(Piece* mx)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            mx[i][j] = new Queen();
        }
    }

}
int main()
{
    Piece * matrix[7][7];
    changeToQueen(matrix); // this fails
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void changeToQueen(Piece* mx[7][7])`

Comment: Judging by the loop conditionals, you need `Piece* matrix[8][8];`.

Comment: You have a memory leak

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in chess, promotion gives you ONE queen, not 64. You should use the location of the pawn, to create a new Queen on that location. Also, you also want to reuse the _color_ of the pawn. You can't promote a white pawn to a black queen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the input argument to `void changeToQueen(Piece * mx[7][7])`.

Or you can change the input argument to `void changeToQueen(Piece** mx)`.
Change the assignment operator to `mx[7*i + j] = new Queen();` and pass in the first element as input `changeToQueen(&(matrix[0][0]));`

The reason why both work is because multidimensional array elements are stored contiguously in memory. So all you need is a pointer to the first element.

Both solutions are a bit flawed because if you need to change the dimensions of your matrix, you have to change your code a bit. Changing your prototype to `void changeToQueen(Piece** mx, size_t width, size_t height)` will be helpful for the future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not understand dependencies between `Queen` and `Piece`, so I suppose that `Piece` is super-type of `Queen` and assignment `Piece * mx = new Queen();` is correct.

To fix the obvious problem of type mismatch you can change your

```
  void changeToQueen(Piece* mx)
```

to

```
  void changeToQueen(Piece* mx[7][7])
```

and with changing loops border to 7 (`for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)`) or size of matrix to `8 x 8` (with the same loops) this will work.

But my suggestion is to think over method of storing data.
Perhaps you will need to build matrix of size different from 7x7, so consider the following example, where dynamic memory is used to store the matrix (in this example only `Queen` is used):

```cpp
void changeToQueen(Queen*** &mx, int size)
{
    mx = new Queen**[size]; // allocation of memory for pointers of the first level
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        mx[i] = new Queen*[size]; // allocation of memory for pointers of the second level
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            mx[i][j] = new Queen(); // allocation of memory for object
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m_size = 7;
    Queen *** matrix = NULL; // now memory not allocated for matrix

    changeToQueen(matrix, m_size);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: `&` sign in `void changeToQueen(Queen*** &mx, int size)` allows to change pointer `Queen *** matrix;` inside the function `changeToQueen`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively this could be a way to handle things

```
template <unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns>
class Board
{
    public:
        Board() {}

        void    changeToQueen()
        {
            for (unsigned int y = 0 ; y < rows ; ++y)
            {
                for (unsigned int x = 0 ; x < columns ; ++x)
                { _pieces[y][x] = Queen(); }
            }
        }

        Piece   &at(unsigned int row, unsigned int column)
        { return _pieces[row][column]; } // you should check for out of range
        // you could either have a default null value for Piece to return, or throw an exception

    private:
        Piece   _pieces[rows][columns];
};

int main()
{
    Board<8,8>  board;

    board.changeToQueen();
    // return 0; // this is not mandatory in c++
}
```

So, yeah, no pointers almost no worries ;)

You still want pointers?? uhm... okay maybe you could do that: `Piece   *_pieces[rows][columns];`, i'm not sure you really need it, but I can't tell how much it would modify your existing code to do this.